# Create R shiny filters from binaries columns

Tags: r, filter, shiny, binaries

I have a data.table that looks like this:

| Sepal.Length | Sepal.Width | Petal.Length | Petal.Width | Species | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5.1 | 3.5 | 1.4 | 0.2 | setosa | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 4.9 | 3.0 | 1.4 | 0.2 | setosa | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4.7 | 3.2 | 1.3 | 0.2 | setosa | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 4.6 | 3.1 | 1.5 | 0.2 | setosa | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

```
set.seed(14)
n = 15
dt[, A := rbinom(n, 1, 0.4)]
dt[, B := rbinom(n, 1, 0.14)]
dt[, C := rbinom(n, 1, 0.57)]
dt[, D := rbinom(n, 1, 0.70)]
dt[, E := rbinom(n, 1, 0.11)]
```

Columns A to E represent categories.

- Row 1 belongs to category B, D and E
- Row 2 belongs to category A
- Row 3 belongs to category A and D ...

I would like to create a filter in an r shiny application with these 5 categories like below :

[image]

- if only filter A is selected, I want it to keep the lines where A == 1
- if filters A and D are selected, I want it to keep the lines where A == 1 & D == 1
- ...

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        "category",
        "Choose a category",
        choices = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
        selected = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
        multiple = T
        
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  filter_data <- reactive({
    # filters
    dt
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    filter_data()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use e.g. base `Reduce` to loop over the selected columns and filter your data sequentially:

```r
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

set.seed(14)
n <- 15

dt <- as.data.table(iris[seq(n), ])

dt[, A := rbinom(n, 1, 0.4)]
dt[, B := rbinom(n, 1, 0.14)]
dt[, C := rbinom(n, 1, 0.57)]
dt[, D := rbinom(n, 1, 0.70)]
dt[, E := rbinom(n, 1, 0.11)]

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        "category",
        "Choose a category",
        choices = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
        selected = c("A", "D"),
        multiple = TRUE
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  filter_data <- reactive({
    Reduce(
      \(x, y) {
        x[x[[y]] == 1, ]
      },
      input$category, init = dt
    )
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    filter_data()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4947
```

[image]

A `dplyr` option would be to use `if_all`:

```
dt |>
      dplyr::filter(if_all(all_of(input$category), ~ . == 1))
```

And another base option using `rowSums`:

```
dt[rowSums(dt[, input$category, with = FALSE]) == length(input$category), ]
```

Comment: Oh thank you, 

do you have any idea on how to deal with automatic filtering datamods::filter_data_server ?

Comment: Well, sure could you use `datamods::filter_data_server`. But that will create an input for each of your columns.

Comment: exactly, any ways to just have one filter for all these columns with *datamods::filter_data_server* ??